# Typescript Function not creating CircleMarker on Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I made a custom function to create CircleMarkers for a given value of "InstancesCount" on a Map.

Previously, I was calling `<CircleMarker>` function directly in the code, which was working fine. But I have decided to create a separate function, but the new function does not seem to be creating the markers on MAP

OLD Code which was creating CircleMarker(working perfectly):

```
    import { LatLngExpression } from "leaflet";

   {
        CityMapData.map((city, index) => 
        {
            const {
                    instancesCount,
                    timeZoneData,
                  } = city;

            return (
                    <CircleMarker
                    key={index}
                    center={timeZoneData.coordinates}
                    radius={10 * Math.log(instancesCount + 1)}
                    fillOpacity={0.5}
                    stroke={false}
                    color={COLORS.RED}
                    >
                   );
        })
   }
```

NEW Code which is NOT creating CircleMarker:

```
    import { LatLngExpression } from "leaflet";

    const createCircleMarkerOnMap = (
                              index: number,
                              instancescount: number,
                              circleColor: string,
                              timezoneData_timeZoneId: string,
                              timezoneData_coordinates: LatLngExpression
    ) => {
    return <CircleMarker
                    key={index}
                    center={timezoneData_coordinates}
                    radius={10 * Math.log(instancescount + 1)}
                    fillOpacity={0.5}
                    stroke={false}
                    color={circleColor}
    >
    </CircleMarker>;
    };


    {
        CityMapData.map((city, index) => 
        {
            const {
                    healthyinstancesCount,
                    unhealthyinstancesCount,
                    timeZoneData,
                  } = city;

            createCircleMarkerOnMap
            (
                index,
                unhealthyinstancesCount,
                "COLORS.RED",
                timeZoneData.timeZoneId,
                timeZoneData.coordinates
            );
            if(showBothHealthyAndUnhealthy)
            {
                   createCircleMarkerOnMap
                   (
                       index,
                       healthyinstancesCount,
                       "COLORS.GREEN",
                       timeZoneData.timeZoneId,
                       timeZoneData.coordinates
                   );
            }
        })
   }
```

Example of Data in City include:

```
City=Phoenix,
instancesCount=56,
timeZoneData.timeZoneId= ET,
timeZoneData.coordinates.Latitude 34.867608,
timeZoneData.coordinates.Longitude=-84.318978
```

Comment: Please provide more context. Is CityMapData a React state? Where is this variable being used?

Comment: @laian CityMapData contains the "instancescount" for each city.

    export interface HealthDataPerEntity {
        entityName: string;
        instancesCount: number;
        }

    interface HealthMapData extends HealthDataPerEntity {
    timeZoneData: ITimeZoneData;
    }
        const CityMapData: HealthMapData[] = [];

Comment: @laian https://i.imgur.com/6fyboTU.png

Comment: are you sure the OLD code works, seems strange since the CircleMarker doesn't have a closing tag like /> 

Also be aware that you can be creating CircleMarker components with the same key, since you use the same index for creating healthyinstancesCount CircleMarker and unhealthyinstancesCount CircleMarker

Also in your new code you don't pass any children to CircleMarker, so it would make more sense to close the tage like <CircleMarker/> instead of <CircleMarker> </CircleMarker>

Answer (score 0):

Probably just missing a `return` statement to output the result of your call to `createCircleMarkerOnMap` function.

But you may be troubled by the possibility to sometimes output 2 elements instead, depending on your `showBothHealthyAndUnhealthy` flag?

In that case, one of the possible solutions could be to use `<React.Fragment>` to wrap the potentially multiple output elements:

```
CityMapData.map((city, index) => 
  {
    const {
      healthyinstancesCount,
      unhealthyinstancesCount,
      timeZoneData,
    } = city;

    // Do not forget to return something from the mapper callback
    return (
      // Use <React.Fragment> to output a single element, but which may contain multiple children
      <React.Fragment key={index}>
        {
          createCircleMarkerOnMap
            (
                index,
                unhealthyinstancesCount,
                "COLORS.RED",
                timeZoneData.timeZoneId,
                timeZoneData.coordinates
            )
        }
        {
          showBothHealthyAndUnhealthy &&
            createCircleMarkerOnMap
              (
                index,
                healthyinstancesCount,
                "COLORS.GREEN",
                timeZoneData.timeZoneId,
                timeZoneData.coordinates
              )
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
);
```

BTW, note that in the case you generate 2 Markers per item, you place them at the exact same coordinates, hence they will visually overlap.